# How do you choose the right load for reliability testing?

Tags: hardware, testing, test-equipment, reliability, electronic-load

I am an automotive reliability and test engineer. I do environmental or electrical tests and during these tests I need to load my products. By load I mean, for example, there is a mosfet driven by a high side driver, what should I connect to this mosfet as a load so that the test conditions are correct.

For example, it is desired that the current passing through the mosfet is 5A by design, but that selected mosfet can give 8A, but we later learn that in real use conditions, the product draws 4A, not 5A. In the light of this information, **how much load do I need to connect to the output of that mosfet during these tests?**

If you know of a standard or article for this, I would appreciate it if you could share it.

Comment: The obvious answer is -- what the product specification says, or whatever standards are referenced therein. I guess that's the question, then? -- You (and/or, by extension, whatever agreement you have with your customer(s) regarding these products) are looking for a standard *with which to test them*?

Comment: @TimWilliams I would like to learn how to test the DUT with a load simulation when testing with a specific standard rather than a standard.

Comment: Ok. I'm not sure how we can answer that then, other than "read the standard".

Comment: This is where the problem starts. For example, there is no information on this subject in the ISO 16750-2 standard, which is used to test automotive components, how should I act in such a case. Standard link http://u.dianyuan.com/bbs/u/44/1156130374.pdf

Comment: 4.8.2 says what to do in that case. If it's not defined (or any tighter) in the suite of standards your product has, it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Load it with the max load it could ever experience, not the operating load. If the max load is a direct short then load it with that. If it's 8A then use that. If the max load burns out the fet the add current protection

Comment: How should I calculate the aging factor if I test this way? Under normal conditions, a load of 4A passes over the product and the life of the product is 1000 hours. During the tests, I run the product in a condition that is 3 times the normal temperature of the product and I call the acceleration factor 3 (as an example) but if I draw 8A from the product at the same time, how should I take this into account?